# How do I update my Texview based on my selection

Tags: android, performance

I have a textview, 2 Checkboxes, 2 RadioButtons.  What ever item I select or deselect should be updated on the textview -  how do I achieve this ??? I know we can do it using an if else but what if the problem turns complex?  For instance, what if I have 10 checkboxes and 10 radio buttons - do I have to write condition for all the views ??

Here is how my code looks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textview;
CheckBox checkbox1;
CheckBox checkbox2;
RadioGroup group1;
RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
static String displayText="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    checkbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkbox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

    group1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_1);
    checkbox1.setOnClickListener(new checkBoxClicked());
    checkbox2.setOnClickListener(new checkBoxClicked());


    radio1.setOnClickListener(new checkBoxClicked());
    radio2.setOnClickListener(new checkBoxClicked());
    textview.setText(displayText);
  class checkBoxClicked implements View.OnClickListener
{

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

        if(radio1.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="radio1";
        }
        if(radio2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="radio2";
        }

        if(checkbox1.isChecked())
        {
            displayText= "checkbox1";
        }
        if(checkbox2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox2";

        }
        if(checkbox1.isChecked()&&checkbox2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox1" + "checkbox2";

        }
        if(checkbox1.isChecked()&&radio1.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox1"+"radio1";
        }
        if(checkbox1.isChecked()&&radio2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox1"+"radio2";
        }
        if(checkbox2.isChecked()&&radio1.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox2"+"radio1";
        }
        if(checkbox2.isChecked()&&radio2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="checkbox2"+"radio2";
        }
        if(radio1.isChecked()&&checkbox1.isChecked()&&checkbox2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="radio1"+"checkbox1"+"checkbox2";
        }
        if(radio2.isChecked()&&checkbox1.isChecked()&&checkbox2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="radio2"+"checkbox1"+"checkbox2";
        }

        if(!checkbox1.isChecked()&&!checkbox2.isChecked()&&!radio1.isChecked()&&!radio2.isChecked())
        {
            displayText="";
        }
       textview.setText(displayText);
 }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the if-else case you have now, but use a StringBuffer instead of a case for each different tuple

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if(radio1.isChecked())
        {
            sb.append("radio1");
        }
        if(radio2.isChecked())
        {
            sb.append("radio2");
        }

        if(checkbox1.isChecked())
        {
            sb.append("checkbox1");
        }
        if(checkbox2.isChecked())
        {
            sb.append("checkbox2");
        }
        textview.setText(sb.toString());
```

this way you only need 1 case per checkbox/radiobutton

Comment: Not a problem! glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.. it should give you the same functionality as your code (except that the radio value will always be at the front of the displayText string) with much less code.

```
displayText = "";

if(radio1.isChecked){
    displayText = "radio1";
}else if(radio2.isChecked){
    displayText = "radio2";
}

if(checkbox1.isChecked){
    displayText += "checkbox1";
}

if(checkbox2.isChecked){
    displayText += "checkbox2";
}

textview.setText(displayText);
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work, I actually did what you have said but it doesn't give the right answer, If i uncheck the checkbox1 it wont delete the value from textview because there isn't any else statement if we start implementing this way then we will endup having the same logic as mine. Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you include the 'displayText = ""' line at the start of the onClick method? It should clear the textView and then only add back the value(s) that are checked.

Oh well.. maybe I am misunderstanding something about your situation.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, Yes your right i forgot to implement the displayText="", it works now !!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity:

```
LinearLayout layout;
TextView textview;
CheckBox checkbox1;
CheckBox checkbox2;
RadioGroup group1;
RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
static String displayText="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

layout = (LinearLayout) findViewByID(R.id.linearlayout);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
checkbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
checkbox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

onClick (assuming the linearlayout was the parent to all the radio buttons and checkboxes):

```
public void onClick() { 
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceOf CompoundButton) { 
           if (v.isChecked) {
              sb.append(v.getText());
           }
        }

}
textView.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define these three methods:

```
private String getText(RadioButton button) {
    if button.isChecked() return button.getText();
    else return "";
}

private String getText(CheckBox box) {
    if box.isChecked() return "checkBox"
    else return "";
}

private void refreshText() {
    TextView t;
    String text = getText(button1) + getText(button2) + getText(checkbox1) + getText(checkbox2);
    t.setText(text);
}
```

Then each of your views should simply call `refreshText()` on click.